# Canvas Pixelation - Adjust pixel size

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got a script that cycle's through images. The images start pixelated and then when they are in view, become unpixelated. I achieve that by calling this function `x` amount of times with `requestAnimationFrame`

```
Images.prototype.setPixels = function() {
    var sw          = this.imageWidth,
        sh          = this.imageHeight,
        imageData   = this.context.getImageData( 0, 0, sw, sh ),
        data        = imageData.data,
        y, x, n, m;

    for ( y = 0; y < sh; y += this.pixelation ) {
        for ( x = 0; x < sw; x += this.pixelation ) {

            var red = data[((sw * y) + x) * 4];
            var green = data[((sw * y) + x) * 4 + 1];
            var blue = data[((sw * y) + x) * 4 + 2];

            for ( n = 0; n < this.pixelation; n++ ) {
                for ( m = 0; m < this.pixelation; m++ ) {
                    if ( x + m < sw ) {
                        data[((sw * (y + n)) + (x + m)) * 4] = red;
                        data[((sw * (y + n)) + (x + m)) * 4 + 1] = green;
                        data[((sw * (y + n)) + (x + m)) * 4 + 2] = blue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.context.putImageData( imageData, 0, 0 );
}
```

**Question: How can I make the individual pixels larger blocks than they are right now.** Right now they are pretty small, and the effect is a little jarring. I'm hoping to fix this by having less pixel blocks on the screen, by making them bigger.

I hope this makes sense, I'm fairly green with canvas, so anything you could do to point me in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best for this kind of effect is to simply use [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and let the browser handle the pixelation thanks to the nearest-neighbor anti-aliasing algorithm that can be set by changing the [`imageSmoothingEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) property to false.

It then becomes a two step process to pixelate an image at any *pixel_size*:

- draw the full quality image (or canvas / video ...) at its original size / *pixel_size*.
  At this stage, each "pixel" is one pixel large.
- draw this small image again but up-scaled by pixel_size. To do so, you just need to draw the canvas over itself.
  Each pixel is now *pixel_size* large.

Instead of dealing with hard to read many parameters of drawImage, we can deal the scaling quite easily by just using `ctx.scale()` method.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawPixelated( source, pixel_size ) {
  // scale down
  ctx.scale(1 / pixel_size, 1 / pixel_size)
  ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  // make next drawing erase what's currently on the canvas
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  // nearest-neighbor
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  // scale up
  ctx.setTransform(pixel_size, 0, 0, pixel_size, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  
  // reset all to defaults
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
}

const img = new Image();
img.onload = animeLoop;
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";

let size = 1;
let speed = 0.1;
function animeLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  size += speed;
  if(size > 30 || size <= 1) {
    speed *= -1
  }

  drawPixelated( img, size );

  requestAnimationFrame(animeLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Now for the ones that come with a real need to use an ImageData, for instance because they are *generating* pixel-art, then know that you can simply use the same technique:

- put your ImageData with each pixel being 1 pixel large.
- scale your context to pixel_size
- draw your canvas over itself upscaled

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function putPixelated( imageData, pixel_size ) {
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  // make next drawing erase what's currently on the canvas
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  // nearest-neighbor
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  // scale up
  ctx.setTransform(pixel_size, 0, 0, pixel_size, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  
  // reset all to defaults
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
}

const img = new ImageData(16, 16);
crypto.getRandomValues(img.data);

let size = 1;
let speed = 0.1;

animeLoop();

function animeLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  size += speed;
  if(size > 30 || size <= 1) {
    speed *= -1
  }

  putPixelated( img, size );

  requestAnimationFrame(animeLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great answer but wouldn't it be better to use save() and restore() instead of manually resetting just in case 'default' isn't the previous state...

Comment: @Synthetx `save()` saves all the properties of the context, that is a big object, `restore` will reapply them all, that's a lot of side-effects. I never use `save()` and `restore()` and always prefer setting only the properties I used and cleaning right after my code. This improves greatly the perfs. The only use case for save and restore is to handle clipping areas, but even this I almost never use and prefer dealing with compositing instead.

Comment: really great answer, thank you! This version performs a lot better too!

Comment: @Kaiido Good to know! Thanks for clarifying.